# CSS only rendering after jQuery animation completes. How to fix that?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a hidden element which I am sliding down using simple `.slideDown()` function. This element has another element inside, but that does not show up until the sliding down is complete.

Here is a fiddle with a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx3tY/). Code are pretty straight forward

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    $("#test").slideDown(1000);
});
```

And

```
<div id="test">
    <div class="hiddenbar">
    </div>

    Long Para
</div>
<a>Click Here</a>
```

The `.hiddenbar` shows up after slideDown completes. Any way to overcome this?

Comment: thats because you´re using position absolute, so the element will be always on top: -4px, ;)

Answer (score 2):

Durning the transition, `#test` gets `overflow: hidden`, which plays hell with negative positions and margins.

Try reworking your layout to not have to use negative values in your positioning: `top`, `left`, etc

Comment: Anyway around the way I am trying or to create similar effect?

Comment: instead of a border on #test, you could nest an element inside #test and give it the border?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, but not best way.

```
$("a").on("click", function() {
    $('.hiddenbar').css('top','0');
    $('#test').slideDown(1000,function(){
        $('.hiddenbar').css('top','-4px');
    });
});
```